# 'There remains...' vs. 'There remain...'

Tags: grammar

Is the sentence below grammatical?

> There remains substantial further time, thought and effort required.

'There remain...' does not sound correct to me in this context.

Comment: This is a construction with _remain_ and dummy _there_. Several rules are being applied. But yes, it's grammatical. Note that the NP _further time, thought, and effort_ is being treated as a unit. Which is not strange, because they're all abstract mass nouns, and we can think of their combination as a dough to be raised.

Comment: A wonderfully insightful answer, John. Thanks so much!

Comment: This construction is odd because of the subject inversion, which is unusual in English.  Having a plural verb before encountering a plural subject creates a strong presumption of plurality that is not met with the first subject word encountered, but only when you realize the subject is a list that together constitute a plural.  I find it easier to align the number of the verb with the first subject encountered and then to accommodate the further items as part of the implied unity.  If you had said: "time, thought, and effort are required," I would have time to expect a plural verb.

Comment: @Vegawatcher 'Health and Safety is our primary concern.' / 'Fish and chips is my favourite meal.' /*'The jury was arguing among themselves.' /*'The jury were reintroduced in 1887, and was then solely used in criminal cases on the second tier of the three-tier Norwegian court system' ([[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jury); mangled].

Comment: Why do we need remains and required both?

Comment: "X remains required" is definitely an odd sentence... And "there remain/s  required" even odder.

Comment: 1 "there remains time" does not mean 2 "there remains time required". "there is time required" means 2.

Answer (score 0):

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/remain)
>
> Remain:
>
> to continue to exist when other parts or other things no longer exist

Hence, the sentence uses the notion of “*time, thought and effort*” as a unified concept, a whole concept. By referring to what *remains* it signifies reference to part of that whole.

Consequently, the implication is: “*Of the whole {singular} there remains {singular} a substantial part {singular}*”. This is grammatical in a simple way.

Footnote: interestingly, Merriam Webster does not cover the whole spectrum of meaning of *remain* offered by Cambridge.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the sentence below grammatical?
>
> There…..remains [substantial further time, thought and effort] [that is] required].
>
> Adverb …..verb …[……………………………………subject………………………………………]

The existential adverb “there” causes subject verb inversion.

The subjects of the sentence are three individual uncountable nouns that are modified by “substantial further” and separated by serial commas – the modifier makes no difference to the verb:

There remains  time, thought and effort [that is] required.

Consider

There **is** a dog in the garden / There **are** two dogs in the garden - The verb agrees with the nearest subject.

There **are** two cats and a dog in the garden - The verb agrees with the nearest subject.

In your example, the nearest subject is “substantial further time” which is singular.